# SQL with 2 variables

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

im doing a SQL to give me show date of a specific cinema with specific movie

i did it and it is working for the cinema. i mean it show me the show date of a specific cinema...i need a way to show also the show date of a specific cinema AND specific movie

```
SELECT show.show_datetime
FROM `cinema`
JOIN `theater` ON `theater`.`cinema_id` = `cinema`.`cinema_id`
JOIN  `show` ON  `show`.`theater_id` =  `theater`.`theater_id` 
WHERE  `cinema`.`cinema_id` = 1
```

please note that i have a table movie and PK with movie_id

Comment: Maby you could show some table schema?

Comment: how we know from which table to pick up movie column?

Comment: what is difference between cineman and movie?

Comment: well..i didnt knw how to give you a schema so i have uploaded a pic 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/837/86816152.jpg/

thnk u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that there is relation between show and movie table on movie_id. so use below query and let me know

```
SELECT show.show_datetime
FROM `cinema`
JOIN `theater` ON `theater`.`cinema_id` = `cinema`.`cinema_id`
JOIN  `show` ON  `show`.`theater_id` =  `theater`.`theater_id` 
JOIN 'movie' ON `show`.`movie_id` =  `movie`.`movie_id` = 
WHERE  `cinema`.`cinema_id` = 1  AND `movie`.`movie_id` = 2
```

Change movie id from 2 to whatever you need

Comment: yea its working...ive just rectify few syntax error...BIG THANK YOU

Comment: Yes most welcome. Sorry i am not php mysql guy so may be you got syntax error. Glad its working.